# How to reindex pandas dataframes of different lengths?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list `series` of pandas dataframes of different lengths. I need to transform them into the dataframes of the same (maximum) length `max_len`.

```
0:
2021-01-20 11:20    4
2021-01-20 11:22    5
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3

1:
2021-01-20 11:00    1
2021-01-20 11:22    2
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3
2021-01-21 10:00    1

2:
2021-01-20 11:20    2
2021-01-20 11:22    5
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3
2021-01-21 9:00     2
```

**Expected result:**

In this example the maximum length is 7. Thus, all dataframes should have the same length:

```
0:
2021-01-20 11:00    NaN
2021-01-20 11:20    4
2021-01-20 11:22    5
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3
2021-01-21 9:00     NaN
2021-01-21 10:00    NaN

1:
2021-01-20 11:00    1
2021-01-20 11:20    NaN
2021-01-20 11:22    2
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3
2021-01-21 9:00     NaN
2021-01-21 10:00    1

2:
2021-01-20 11:00    NaN
2021-01-20 11:20    2
2021-01-20 11:22    5
2021-01-20 11:23    4 
2021-01-20 11:40    3
2021-01-21 9:00     2
2021-01-21 10:00    NaN
```

This is my code:

```
for i in range(len(series)):
    if len(series[i])!= max_len:
        series[i] = series[i].reindex(longest_series.index)
```

However, the `reindex` results in an i-th dataframe with **all** Nan values. Also, I'm not sure how to retrieve `max_len`.

How can I have Nan values only in new index values in each dataframe?

**Update:**

```
selected_series = []

l = pd.DataFrame([{'2021-01-20 11:20': 4, '2021-01-20 11:22': 5, '2021-01-20 11:23': 4, '2021-01-20 11:40': 3}])
selected_series.append(l)
l = pd.DataFrame([{'2021-01-20 11:00': 1, '2021-01-20 11:22': 2, '2021-01-20 11:23': 4, '2021-01-20 11:40': 3, '2021-01-21 10:00': 1}])
selected_series.append(l)
l = pd.DataFrame([{'2021-01-20 11:20': 2, '2021-01-20 11:22': 5, '2021-01-20 11:23': 4, '2021-01-20 11:40': 3, '2021-01-21 9:00': 2}])
selected_series.append(l)
```

Comment: Can you provide your input as python object?

Comment: Try joining each DataFrame in your Series on the `date` with a "template" DataFrame with all the datetimes. Note that your expected output will not contain integers, as `NaN` is a float, so the entire column will be converted to `float`.

Comment: @ddejohn: What if I have thousands dataframes in my real case?

Comment: See my answer @Fluxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do indeed have a `Series` of `DataFrame` objects, then this should work:

```py
s.apply(lambda df: pd.merge(template.copy(), df, on="date", how="outer"))
```

Where `s` is a series of DataFrame objects with datetime column "date" and "value" column of any type, and `template` is a DataFrame representing all the rows each DataFrame in your series *should* have:

```py
                 date
0 2021-01-20 11:00:00
1 2021-01-20 11:20:00
2 2021-01-20 11:22:00
3 2021-01-20 11:23:00
4 2021-01-20 11:40:00
5 2021-01-21 09:00:00
6 2021-01-21 10:00:00
```

Note: your `DataFrame` objects in your series need to have column names for this to work easily.

Result:

```py
In [5]: s[0]  # first dataframe in series s
                 date  value
0 2021-01-20 11:00:00    NaN
1 2021-01-20 11:20:00    4.0
2 2021-01-20 11:22:00    5.0
3 2021-01-20 11:23:00    4.0
4 2021-01-20 11:40:00    3.0
5 2021-01-21 09:00:00    NaN
6 2021-01-21 10:00:00    NaN
```

To create a `template` DataFrame, from e.g. June 20, 2020 to June 21, 2020, in increments of 5 minutes:

```py
template = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2020-06-20", "2020-06-22", freq="5T"))
```

Comment: What is "template"?

Comment: How can I create "template"? That's my key challenge

Comment: It's explained in my answer... It's a DataFrame with a single column, `"date"`.

Comment: Your original question implies that every DataFrame in your series should contain that list of datetimes...

Comment: yes, but how can I get all these unique dates from different dataframes? Each dataframe may have a different subset of datetimes.

Comment: You've woefully mis-represented your problem. Is there a *single* range of dates that *all* the DataFrames should be contained within? If not, then your question is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pandas.concat` on the columns, then split again:

```
df = pd.concat(selected_series).T
lst = list(zip(*df.iteritems()))[1]
```

output:

```
(2021-01-20 11:20    4.0
 2021-01-20 11:22    5.0
 2021-01-20 11:23    4.0
 2021-01-20 11:40    3.0
 2021-01-20 11:00    NaN
 2021-01-21 10:00    NaN
 2021-01-21 9:00     NaN
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 2021-01-20 11:20    NaN
 2021-01-20 11:22    2.0
 2021-01-20 11:23    4.0
 2021-01-20 11:40    3.0
 2021-01-20 11:00    1.0
 2021-01-21 10:00    1.0
 2021-01-21 9:00     NaN
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 2021-01-20 11:20    2.0
 2021-01-20 11:22    5.0
 2021-01-20 11:23    4.0
 2021-01-20 11:40    3.0
 2021-01-20 11:00    NaN
 2021-01-21 10:00    NaN
 2021-01-21 9:00     2.0
 Name: 0, dtype: float64)
```

Comment: I get this error: `
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: This error is thrown by line `df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)`, where `l` is the list of pandas dataframes.

Comment: It's a list of **Series** in my case, thus my request for you to provide the unambiguous input as python object ;)

Comment: How can I extract the Python object

Comment: You can  use `to_dict`, otherwise type it ;) Check the top of my answer as example

Comment: Sure, please see the updated question.

Comment: @Fluxy this is not a list of "*dataframes of different lengths*" but of a single DataFrame ;)

Comment: My sincere apologies...:( I've just fixed it. Now it's exactly the same as I have in my code.

Comment: @Fluxy no worries, then check the update, the logic was almost the same ;)